# p-table with pEditableColumn is replacing value for second table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have two tables (p-table) with editing rows. But, when I update the row value in the first table, it updates the second table too.
How could I set this tables rows as unique?

-> Table component:

```
<p-table [value]="coberturas" dataKey="id" editMode="row">
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
  <tr>
    <th class="width-20rem">
      {{ t("coberturas.dadosCobertura.tabela.cobertura") }}
    </th>
    <th>{{ t("layout.topicosComuns.capitalIndividual") }}</th>
    <th>{{ t("coberturas.dadosCobertura.tabela.vlrMin") }}</th>
    <th>{{ t("coberturas.dadosCobertura.tabela.vlrMax") }}</th>
    <th>{{ t("layout.topicosComuns.capitalGlobal") }}</th>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-cobertura>
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{ cobertura.nomeMatrizCobertura }}
    </td>
    <td pEditableColumn>
      <p-cellEditor>
        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
          <p-dropdown
            *ngIf="cobertura.codigoMatrizCobertura == 819"
            [(ngModel)]="auxilioFuneral"
            [options]="auxiliosFunerais"
            optionLabel="valor"
            [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
          ></p-dropdown>
          <input
            *ngIf="cobertura.codigoMatrizCobertura != 819"
            [(ngModel)]="cobertura.capitalIndividual"
            pInputText
            type="text"
            required
          />
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
          {{ cobertura.capitalIndividual }}
        </ng-template>
      </p-cellEditor>
    </td>
    <td pEditableColumn>
      <p-cellEditor>
        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
          {{ cobertura.valorMatrizMinimoImportancia | realPipe }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
          {{ cobertura.valorMatrizMinimoImportancia | realPipe }}
        </ng-template>
      </p-cellEditor>
    </td>
    <td pEditableColumn>
      <p-cellEditor>
        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
          {{ cobertura.valorMatrizMaximoImportancia | realPipe }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
          {{ cobertura.valorMatrizMaximoImportancia | realPipe }}
        </ng-template>
      </p-cellEditor>
    </td>
    <td pEditableColumn></td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

I'm setting two tables with two different values, each 'als-tabela-cotacao' is the component above

```
    <als-tabela-cotacao
  *ngIf="!tabelaSocio"
  [coberturas]="listaCoberturasEmpregados"
></als-tabela-cotacao>

<als-tabela-cotacao
  *ngIf="tabelaSocio"
  [coberturas]="listaCoberturasSocios"
></als-tabela-cotacao>
```

Comment: how do you define `listaCoberturasEmpregados` and `listaCoberturasSocios` in your component class?

Comment: @akkonrad  this.listarCotacoes
        .listarCoberturas(dadoRqListCobetura)
        .subscribe((res) => {
          this.listaCoberturas = res.data;

          this.listaCoberturasEmpregados =
            res.data.listaOcorrenciaMatrizCobertura;
          this.listaCoberturasSocios = res.data.listaOcorrenciaMatrizCobertura;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you're doing is you're assigning same thing (`res.data.listaOcorrenciaMatrizCobertura`) to both variables `listaCoberturasEmpregados` and `listaCoberturasSocios`. For javascript it's still the same, since it's refers to the same original variable. What I'd recommend is to use a destruct operator to create a copy of the array = `this.listaCoberturasSocios = [...res.data.listaOcorrenciaMatrizCobertura]`

Here you can check a working example how to do it, uncomment the code to see proper solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ih6bod?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: oh, that's right. thank you so much!